# Retention of players (month wise) through Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

Is there any way where I know month wise Retention of players who has installled my app through different dynamic links.

Ex.
Through Dynamic Link1 i got 100 installs in 1st month.
Through Dynamic Link2 i got 200 installs in 1st month.

2nd month-
Users who installed app through Link1 - out of 100 users only 50 continued.
Users who installed app through Link2 - out of 200 users only 100 continued.

Should we get these data on firebase. If yes, please just give me what should I look into and if possible How ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save referal url and count.